# How to work properly with promises in JavaScript after closing the browser?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am using firebase or pouchsb / couchdb + vuejs / quasar.
My architecture does not imply a server layer as such.

There is a task of the following nature. Let's say that at 14:00 the user creates an order that must be executed at 15:00. What if the browser is closed and then reopened at 14:58?

How to make a promise to be fulfilled after closing and reopening the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. When the browser is closed (or the page existed) the JS environment goes away and all promises disappear. You need to take a different approach.

A typical approach would be to store the data about the order in (for example) [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and then:

- Delete it when the order is executed
- Read it when the page is loaded and:

  - put pending orders back on the queue
  - handle out-of-date orders however you like (e.g. display an error or submit them late)